# Cholesky/LDLt that works for singular matrices?

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

**TLDR**
When given $A=X'X$ decomposition, user298737 works by relying on QRDecomposition on $X$. If we didn't have this decomposition, one could use QR to get full-rank part of $A$ and use Cholesky on that, and then project back to original space like in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4502026/998). However, this requires full QR decomposition whereas Mathematica only provides reduced QR decomposition.

Cholesky decomposition fails for matrices that are singular in machine precision. Earlier question [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255970/cholesky-like-rank-revealing-decomposition-on-singular-matrices/256531#256531) to use LDTLt in `ResourceFunction["RationalCholeskyDecomposition"]`, which is more robust than `CholeskyDecomposition`, but still fails if the matrix is too close to singular.

Any tips what I can do in Mathematica to deal with effectively singular matrices?

LDLt decomposition of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ has a statistical [interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579315/statistical-interpretation-of-diagonal-of-cholesky-decomposition) if we treat $X$ as data matrix of rows $x$ :

- $i$th row of $L$ give coefficients of optimal predictive model that predicts $i$'th entry of $x$ from previous entries
- entries of $D$ gives residual variances of models
- For singular $X^T X$, bottom rows of $L$ have a lot of freedom, problem is ill-posed

Example below computes total residual variance using Cholesky/LDLt, but this fails for numerically singular matrices.

```
SeedRandom[1];
dataSize = 30;
dimSize = 30;
sigma = DiagonalMatrix@Table[Exp[-i^2], {i, 1, dimSize}];
X = Normalize /@ 
   RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[sigma], dataSize];
gram = X\[Transpose] . X;
chol2 = ResourceFunction["RationalCholeskyDecomposition"];

(* Total residual variance of best model predicting x[i] from x[j], j<i *)
Total@Last@chol2@gram
```

Fails with `Divide::indet: Indeterminate expression 0./0. encountered.`

Comment: Is efficiency important?

Comment: Ideally it would be faster that reducing it to solving $n$ least-squares problems (I'll post that solution in a bit)

Comment: [Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html) is exactly for isolating the (numerically) singular part of a matrix from the non-singular part.

Comment: Perhaps Householdertransformation `QRDecomposition ` helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given a real square matrix $X$ you are asking for an upper triangular real matrix $R$ such that $X^T X = R^T R$. One could use a QR decomposition $X = QR$, since then
$$X^TX = (QR)^T QR = R^T (Q^TQ) R = R^T R$$
If we also want the diagonal entries to be nonnegative, then we need a little adjustment:

```
CholeskyDecompositionOfXTX[X_]:=With[{R=Last[QRDecomposition[X]]},
                                  Map[If[Negative[#],-1,1]&,Diagonal[R]]*R];
```

**Example.**

```
(* example of an almost singular matrix *)
X = With[{n=40}, Array[N[Range[0,1,1/n]]^#&,n]];

(* calculate Cholesky and check *)
R = CholeskyDecompositionOfXTX[X];
UpperTriangularMatrixQ[R] (* true *)
And@@Thread[Diagonal[R]>=0] (* true *)
Norm[Transpose[R].R-Transpose[X].X] (* small *)
```

Comment: Nice! That works. Also Ben Grossman posted a recipe for how to do this with QR when you don't have $X^T X$ decomposition provided, although my first attempt to turn this into Mathematica didn't work (ie, QRDecomposition gives rectangular matrices, his recipe expected square) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4502026/998

Answer (score 4):

You can find a rational approximation to a specified accuracy.

```
With[{ϵ = 10^-12},
  gramrat = Rationalize[gram, ϵ];
  cholrat = 
   CholeskyDecomposition[
    gramrat + ϵ IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[gram]]];
  ];

gram - Transpose[cholrat] . cholrat // Abs // Max
(* 1.4726*10^-12 *)
```

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but it might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 4):

In [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) we have a code for calculating the LDL decomposition that will handle singular matrices using a pivoting strategy. See [documentation](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/master/DOCUMENTATION#ldl-decomposition) for details. Don't expect it to be efficient though. Also you can use `LDLDecomposition` instead of `NCLDLDecomposition` if you only have numerical entries.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an approach (`hackedLdl`) which takes $X$ and produces LDLt decomposition of $X^T X$. Gives same results as `ResourceFunction["RationalCholeskyDecomposition"][Transpose[X].X]` most of the time, but also seems to work for nearly singular matrices. Unclear how to extend this to the case when $A=X^T X$ decomposition is not available.

```
X1 = {{-2, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -2}, {-2, 0, 1}};
X2 = {{-2, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -2, -2}, {-2, 0, 1, 1}};

On[Assert];
(* Returns coefficients needed to predict i'th coordinate from \
previous coords *)
onlyFirstKColumns[data_, k_] := Module[{n},
   n = Last@Dimensions@data;
   Drop[data\[Transpose], -(n - k)]\[Transpose]
   ];
extractKColumn[data_, k_] := data[[All, {k}]];


phiL2R[i_, data_] := Module[{},
   coefs = Switch[i,
     1,
     {},  (* empty list, 
     since no "previous coordinates" for the first coord *)
     _,
     (* Drop[data\[Transpose],-(n-i+1)]\[Transpose];  (* predictors, 
     drop columns > i *) *)
     Y1 = onlyFirstKColumns[data, i - 1];
     Y2 = extractKColumn[data, i];(* target variable, column i *)
     p = LeastSquares[Y1\[Transpose] . Y1, (Y1\[Transpose] . Y2)];
     residuals = Y2 - Y1 . p;
     Flatten@p
     ];
   (* pad column with zeros *)
   PadRight[coefs, n]
   ];

hackedLdl[X_] := Module[{},
   n = Length@First@X;
   coefsLeftToRight = Table[phiL2R[i, X], {i, n}]\[Transpose];
   l = Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n] - coefsLeftToRight];
   R2 = X - X . coefsLeftToRight;
   d = Total[#*#] & /@ Transpose[R2];
   {l\[Transpose], DiagonalMatrix@d}
   ];
{l, d} = hackedLdl[X1];
Print["L=", l // MatrixForm];
Print["d=", d // MatrixForm];
Print["Equality test1: ", 
  l . d . l\[Transpose] == X1\[Transpose] . X1];

{l, d} = hackedLdl[X2];
Print["L=", l // MatrixForm];
Print["d=", d // MatrixForm];
Print["Equality test2: ", 
  l . d . l\[Transpose] == X2\[Transpose] . X2];

SeedRandom[1];
dataSize = 30;
dimSize = 30;
sigma = DiagonalMatrix@Table[Exp[-i^2], {i, 1, dimSize}];
X3 = Normalize /@ 
   RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[sigma], dataSize];
gram = X3\[Transpose] . X3;
{l, d} = hackedLdl[X3];
Print["Equality test3: ", 
  Max[Abs[Flatten[l . d . l\[Transpose] - X3\[Transpose] . X3]]] < 
   10^-10];
```